# Submit a URL as data in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26.

I got an Input Text box which contains a URL and I want to submit the URL and stored it in the Database using Jquery AJAX.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<input type="text" id="testing" value="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
```

This is the JQuery part:

```
  var whatContent=$("#testing").val();
      var curl="http://localhost:8080/test/grab/"+whatContent;
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: curl,   
      success: function(data) {    
      alert(data);}
      });
```

This is the code for the Action in the Controller:

```
function grab($w=null){
   if($w!=null){
     return $w;
    }
}
```

The code worked and I could see the Alert Message pop up, but there was something missing in the message. I mean I supposed to see the whole URL like this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

But not, I just saw part of it instead:

> http://stackoverflow.com

Later I altered the value in the Input Text box like this:

```
<input type="text" id="testing" value="https://stackoverflow.com/faq">
```

But again, the returned value was still

> http://stackoverflow.com

cakePHP seemed to conside the URL as some parameters rather than a URL.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What you would do to a URL that contains some special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382061/what-you-would-do-to-a-url-that-contains-some-special-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append the content to the end of your "curl" variable like you are, you are attempting to add it to be retrieved through a `GET` variable and will get a result in a request like `http://localhost:8080/test/grab/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`. Clearly this is an invalid request. Your `GET` variable parsing is not going to be consistent and a dangerous way of passing data back to your controller (especially if users will be able to edit the appended value).

Instead, you should use the `data` attribute in jQuery to pass this information back in your POST request as described in the instructions here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

On the Cake side, you'll be able to receive this value as `$this->data['IDValueYouConfigured']`. For example, if your AJAX request was like:

```
  var whatContent=$("#testing").val();
  var curl="http://localhost:8080/test/grab/";
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: curl,
  data: "formValue="+whatContent,   
  success: function(data) {    
  alert(data);}
  });
```

where `formValue` is the `IDValueYouConfigured` that I mentioned earlier.

More importantly, you seem to be misunderstanding proper use of the Cake framework and could be performing all of these functions MUCH more simply using things like the [JsHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js), [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1383/Form), etc. I would recommend using the most RECENT version of [Cake (1.3.3)](http://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/downloads) and follow through the [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) at least once. This will lead to [better questions](http://www.gerv.net/hacking/how-to-ask-good-questions/) which will be more likely to get helpful answers. Hope this helps.