# What you would do to a URL that contains some special characters

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26
I got an Input Text box which contains a URL and I want to submit the URL and stored it in the Database using Jquery AJAX.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<input type="text" id="testing" value="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
```

This is the JQuery part:

```
  var whatContent=$("#testing").val();
      var curl="http://localhost:8080/test/grab/"+whatContent;
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: curl,   
      success: function(data) {    
      alert(data);}
      });
```

This is the code for the Action in the Controller:

```
function grab($w=null){
   if($w!=null){
     return $w;
    }
}
```

The code worked and I could see the Alert Message pop up, but it showed:
https://stackoverflow.com/
instead of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I have tried using escape(whatContent), and encodeURI(whatContent), but they could not help,
the Alert box still showed me
https://stackoverflow.com/
instead of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I am not sure how to do with the URL data that contains some special characters in it.

Comment: What happens if you do `encodeURIComponent(whatContent)`?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the processing on the server side.

Comment: Thanks nick and Gumbo for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a `debug($w)` in you controller action could reveal something.
What is the output of other input than the address that is your goal?

Answer (score 3):

Seems funny to do a POST request, but append the data onto the URL. Either user GET, and `escape(whatContent)`, or use POST, and pass whatContent as the data parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to be logged into SO to ask a question? It would make sense that SO is just redirecting your request to the main page.

Comment: You **don't** have to be logged in to ask a question on SO, there's no such redirect.  Simple to test, log out and try it.  Besides, he's not making any request to SO, he's just passing text to a page that *happens* to be a URL.